# How to unit test without connecting to the database

Tags: java

Basically I want to run the test case that Spring Boot app starts. I need this!

```
@SpringBootTest
 class ApplicationTest {
 

@Test
void contextLoads() {

}
}
```

Should be straight forward like this the problem is that **it tries to connect to the database on `DynamoDbClient.create()`** and I don't want to do that. I just want to test that the spring boot app starts (I don't want to connect to anything)

My service tries to make a connection to the database in the `initialize()`

```
public class MyService {

    private final DynamoService<User> dynamoService;

 
    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize() {
        dynamoService = DynamoService.getInstance(); // THIS IS THE ISSUE
    }




 public class DynamoService<T> {
    private static DynamoService<?> instance;
    @Getter
    private final DynamoDbClient dynamoDbClient;

    private DynamoService() {
        this.dynamoDbClient = DynamoDbClient.create(); // THIS IS THE ISSUE
    }

    public static synchronized <T> DynamoService<T> getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DynamoService<>();
        }
        return (DynamoService<T>) instance;
    }
```

I was trying to mock things and it's just a mess and just doesn't work. I have no idea what to do

```
    @SpringBootTest
class ApplicationTest {
    @Mock
    private DynamoDbClient dynamoDbClientMock = mock(DynamoDbClient.class);

    private DynamoService<?> dynamoService;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        when(DynamoDbClient.create()).thenReturn(mock(DynamoDbClient.class));
        dynamoService = new DynamoService<>(dynamoDbClientMock);
    }

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {

    }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Mocking a database is how you unit test around that interface.  "I was trying to mock things and it's just a mess and just doesn't work" isn't an out for that problem.

Comment: @possum the issue is that it's not mocking. Still trying to connect with the DynamoDbClient.create()